# An example of an infinite non-abelian solvable group

Tags: group-theory

This isn't exactly a homework problem-- it's on a sample exam.

My first instinct is to look to matrix groups, since they are very often non-abelian and infinite, but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: I think your instinct was right in considering matrix groups. Maybe you could check that the subgroup of invertible upper triangular matrices is solvable (start with $2$ by $2$ matrices to get the idea).

Comment: If you know dihedral groups, try the infinite dihedral group.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll look into these suggestions.

Comment: @yoyo: Does that work? Or do you mean something other than unit norm quaternions? Those contain $SU(2)$, and that is simple, so hardly solvable?

Comment: @yoyo: True, but my main point was that in which way will the unit quaternions form a **solvable** group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I confess that the only example that comes to mind is the one Joel mentions in the comments: the subgroup $B$ of $GL_n(K)$, where $K$ is an infinite field and $n \geq 2$, consisting of invertible upper triangular matrices. Let's work this out when $n = 2$. Then
\[
B = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix} \Bigg|\  a, d \in K^*, b \in K\right\}.
\]
This is infinite because $K$ is, and if $d$ is an element of $K^*$ not equal to $1$ then
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\]
do not commute. There's a homomorphism $B \to K^* \times K^*$ sending a general element as above to the diagonal $(a, d)$. It's surjective and the kernel is the normal subgroup
\[
U = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \Bigg|\   b \in K\right\}
\]
of $B$. And as yoyo says in the comments, $U$ is isomorphic to the additive group of $K$. We get an abelian tower
\[
B \supset U\supset \{I\}
\]
If $n > 2$ then there are more steps in the tower; I think this example is written out in the general case in first chapter of Lang's *Algebra*. For $n = 3$ our $U$ is the [Heisenberg group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group), which is interesting enough.

Comment: 2 by 2 unipotent matrices over a field $k$ is abelian (isomorphic $(k,+)$)

Comment: Change the top-left 1 to be an arbitrary invertible ring element and you get AGL(1,K), a non-abelian solvable group.

Comment: @Jyrki This was meant to be the first step beneath the triangular group. I'll edit to make this clearer.

Comment: [I just didn't want to write out $\begin{pmatrix}* & * \\ 0 & *\end{pmatrix}$, and I think that caused trouble in the end.]

Comment: Things are now written out in gory detail. I thought the original answer was alright under a charitable interpretation of my words, but it's hopefully better now.

Answer (score 14):

How about $S_3 \times \mathbb Z$.